# C# ms access and clause

Tags: c#, ms-access

How do I use the C# "and" clause using a Microsoft Access database?

```
String firstname="saket" ;
String lastname="sharma" ;

String query = "select * from table where fname ="firstname" AND lname = "lastname" " ;
```

Comment: You could look up the correct syntax and maybe read up on "bind parameters", but otherwise, is there an actual problem you are having? Do you get errors?

Comment: Please read **[ask]**.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for escaping the double quotes and string formatting.

String query = $"select * from table where fname =\"{firstname}\" AND lname = \"{lastname}\" " ;

Comment: This code is wide open to a [SQL Injection Attack](http://bobby-tables.com/). You need to learn how to do [parameterized queries in C#](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp).